# Manually generate Firebase firestore document ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

i want to generate Document ID manually for firestore, is this possible. The scenario will be a Record of cars. Example

```
Car: {
  chasisNumber : "Ab129011", <-- // always unique
  modelNumber : "2020MBW",
  year : "2020",
  name : "BMW",
}
```

In this scenario i want to create **chasisNumber** as *document ID* because it is unique,
how can i do this. I want this scenario in React-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first example in the Firestore documentation on [adding data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) shows, you can pass any value to the `doc` call to use that as the document ID.

So:

```
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("cities").doc("Ab129011").set({
  chasisNumber : "Ab129011",
  modelNumber : "2020MBW",
  year : "2020",
  name : "BMW",
})
```

Comment: how can i tag you in stack if i have a query